# Create an alternate data stream mid batch file run

Tags: batch-file, ads

I'm trying to create a file in a batch scrript, and also create a ADS (alternate data stream) to the same file, the script looks like this:

```
@echo off


echo. 2>notSecret.txt

echo. 2>notSecret.txt:secret

@echo this is not a secret file... or is it :O > notSecret.txt

@echo this is the secret part! > notSecret.txt:secret
@echo great work >>notSecret.txt:secret
@echo you found it >> notSecret.txt:secret
```

the file is created, but it's ADS isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add a `.txt` file extension to the ADS echo

```
@echo off

echo this is not a secret file... or is it :O > notSecret.txt

echo this is the secret part! > notSecret.txt:Secret.txt
```

Comment: Worked for me only with the extension

Comment: there is no requirement whatsover to use an extenion for the stream name. The syntax is `filename:streamname:streamtype` See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-streams)